# Set restart in ShardingTest

Tags: mongodb, sharding

ShardingTest() object could be used to create a testing sharding, which I would like to use for simple development and testing.

Howevere, I could not restart the testing db I have created before, as using following commands:

```
mongo --nodb
cluster = new ShardingTest({shards:3, chunksize:1, config:3, rs:{nodes:{r1:{startClean:false},r2:{startClean:false},a:{startClean:false}}}})
```

I have tried with the following with no luck:

```
cluster = new ShardingTest({shards:3, chunksize:1, restart:true, config:3, rs:{nodes:{r1:{startClean:false},r2:{startClean:false},a:{startClean:false}}}})
```

Does there is any way to restart the previous setup shard, please?

I have to insert every records everytimes I restart the shard, which is very time-consuming.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

ShardingTest doesn't persist the data in shards like a real MongoDB setup so if your testing needs need persistence, another tool is warranted.

A nice tool for quickly setting up development MongoDB clusters is [mlaunch](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools/wiki/mlaunch).